# Changing color of maximum bar in each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to color the maximum bar within each facet (here, each player) differently than the others. Instead, my code below colors the maximum bar across all facets. How can I fix this?

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(ggthemes)

    df %>% 
      group_by(Player, Theme) %>% summarise(Likes = mean(fb_Likes)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Theme, y = Likes), color = "white") + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(group = Player, fill = Likes == max(Likes))) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c('#888888', '#333333') ) +
      theme_tufte(base_size = 12, 
                  base_family = "sans", 
                  ticks = TRUE) + 
      coord_flip() +   
      theme(legend.position = "none", panel.background = element_blank()) +
      facet_grid(Player ~., space = "free")
```

Here's the data:

```
df <- structure(list(Player = c("Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", 
"Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ozil", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", "Ronaldo", 
"Ronaldo", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", "Neymar", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Bale", 
"Bale", "Bale", "Bale", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", "Pogba", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", 
"Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez", "Suarez"), Theme = c("02 Personal", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", "03 Sponsorship", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "04 Pop Culture", 
"02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", "10 Other Athletes", 
"03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "11 Other", "03 Sponsorship", 
"11 Other", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", "10 Other Athletes", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "11 Other", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "07 Politics", 
"03 Sponsorship", "06 Shoutout", "08 Throwback", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "11 Other", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"02 Personal", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", 
"10 Other Athletes", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"02 Personal", "08 Throwback", "05 Onfield Performance", "10 Other Athletes", 
"10 Other Athletes", "10 Other Athletes", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"11 Other", "11 Other", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "08 Throwback", 
"11 Other", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", "10 Other Athletes", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", "02 Personal", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "02 Personal", "10 Other Athletes", 
"02 Personal", "02 Personal", "10 Other Athletes", "10 Other Athletes", 
"08 Throwback", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", 
"02 Personal", "00 Upcoming Season", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", 
"02 Personal", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"03 Sponsorship", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", "03 Sponsorship", 
"03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", "02 Personal", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "01 Charities", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "00 Upcoming Season", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "02 Personal", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"01 Charities", "05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "03 Sponsorship", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"03 Sponsorship", "00 Upcoming Season", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", 
"02 Personal", "00 Upcoming Season", "03 Sponsorship", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"03 Sponsorship", "00 Upcoming Season", "03 Sponsorship", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"02 Personal", "00 Upcoming Season", "00 Upcoming Season", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "02 Personal", "03 Sponsorship", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "00 Upcoming Season", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"02 Personal", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", "01 Charities", 
"02 Personal", "03 Sponsorship", "02 Personal", "03 Sponsorship", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", "06 Shoutout", 
"01 Charities", "05 Onfield Performance", "01 Charities", "01 Charities", 
"03 Sponsorship", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "04 Pop Culture", 
"01 Charities", "01 Charities", "01 Charities", "02 Personal", 
"01 Charities", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", "06 Shoutout", 
"01 Charities", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "01 Charities", 
"04 Pop Culture", "01 Charities", "01 Charities", "01 Charities", 
"02 Personal", "01 Charities", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", 
"01 Charities", "03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"07 Politics", "03 Sponsorship", "02 Personal", "01 Charities", 
"03 Sponsorship", "01 Charities", "01 Charities", "03 Sponsorship", 
"01 Charities", "01 Charities", "05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"03 Sponsorship", "01 Charities", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"02 Personal", "01 Charities", "01 Charities", "03 Sponsorship", 
"02 Personal", "01 Charities", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"01 Charities", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", "11 Other", "06 Shoutout", 
"06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", 
"06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"01 Charities", "05 Onfield Performance", "06 Shoutout", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"06 Shoutout", "02 Personal", "07 Politics", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", "02 Personal", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "07 Politics", "06 Shoutout", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"10 Other Athletes", "05 Onfield Performance", "03 Sponsorship", 
"08 Throwback", "05 Onfield Performance", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "05 Onfield Performance", "03 Sponsorship", 
"03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", "03 Sponsorship", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "06 Shoutout", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", 
"02 Personal", "02 Personal", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"03 Sponsorship", "00 Upcoming Season", "03 Sponsorship", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", "10 Other Athletes", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "02 Personal", "08 Throwback", "00 Upcoming Season", 
"00 Upcoming Season", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", "03 Sponsorship", 
"02 Personal", "02 Personal", "03 Sponsorship", "02 Personal", 
"02 Personal", "02 Personal", "07 Politics", "08 Throwback", 
"03 Sponsorship", "10 Other Athletes", "03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"03 Sponsorship", "11 Other", "11 Other", "03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", 
"02 Personal", "02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"02 Personal", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"08 Throwback", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "02 Personal", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "11 Other", "02 Personal", "10 Other Athletes", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "02 Personal", "08 Throwback", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", 
"02 Personal", "11 Other", "05 Onfield Performance", "08 Throwback", 
"11 Other", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", "03 Sponsorship", 
"02 Personal", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "02 Personal", 
"06 Shoutout", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "02 Personal", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", "10 Other Athletes", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "06 Shoutout", "02 Personal", 
"10 Other Athletes", "10 Other Athletes", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", 
"10 Other Athletes", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "10 Other Athletes", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "06 Shoutout", "11 Other", "11 Other", 
"06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", "06 Shoutout", 
"10 Other Athletes", "04 Pop Culture", "02 Personal", "02 Personal", 
"02 Personal", "05 Onfield Performance", "07 Politics", "02 Personal", 
"10 Other Athletes", "02 Personal", "11 Other", "10 Other Athletes", 
"07 Politics", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "02 Personal", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "05 Onfield Performance", "02 Personal", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "03 Sponsorship", "02 Personal", "07 Politics", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "07 Politics", "07 Politics", "07 Politics", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "02 Personal", 
"11 Other", "03 Sponsorship", "05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"03 Sponsorship", "03 Sponsorship", "07 Politics", "02 Personal", 
"10 Other Athletes", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "03 Sponsorship", 
"09 Off-field Responsibilities", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"02 Personal", "02 Personal", "07 Politics", "03 Sponsorship", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "03 Sponsorship", 
"03 Sponsorship", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "07 Politics", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"10 Other Athletes", "05 Onfield Performance", "11 Other", "02 Personal", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "03 Sponsorship", "07 Politics", "07 Politics", 
"07 Politics", "07 Politics", "07 Politics", "09 Off-field Responsibilities", 
"10 Other Athletes", "06 Shoutout", "05 Onfield Performance", 
"10 Other Athletes", "10 Other Athletes", "03 Sponsorship", "10 Other Athletes", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "05 Onfield Performance", "02 Personal", 
"05 Onfield Performance", "07 Politics"), fb_Likes = c(147000L, 
162000L, 332000L, 439000L, 319000L, 167000L, 330000L, 298000L, 
278000L, 208000L, 154000L, 185000L, 231000L, 239000L, 488000L, 
155000L, 196000L, 478000L, 216000L, 141000L, 194000L, 202000L, 
274000L, 359000L, 158000L, 595000L, 182000L, 185000L, 80000L, 
135000L, 260000L, 272000L, 164000L, 271000L, 105000L, 158000L, 
204000L, 121000L, 135000L, 178000L, 63000L, 149000L, 119000L, 
147000L, 249000L, 284000L, 180000L, 593000L, 213000L, 225000L, 
241000L, 181000L, 208000L, 203000L, 296000L, 125000L, 435000L, 
328000L, 216000L, 252000L, 226000L, 231000L, 345000L, 307000L, 
338000L, 576000L, 289000L, 212000L, 312000L, 874000L, 386000L, 
96000L, 197000L, 556000L, 97000L, 930000L, 176000L, 1600000L, 
785000L, 579000L, 622000L, 1600000L, 1000000L, 697000L, 661000L, 
189000L, 1400000L, 627000L, 681000L, 985000L, 727000L, 1000000L, 
929000L, 978000L, 847000L, 1300000L, 854000L, 908000L, 1000000L, 
815000L, 148000L, 680000L, 916000L, 517000L, 161000L, 1400000L, 
974000L, 598000L, 1600000L, 798000L, 135000L, 1200000L, 1200000L, 
1400000L, 511000L, 935000L, 425000L, 686000L, 581000L, 716000L, 
1300000L, 828000L, 671000L, 848000L, 545000L, 633000L, 91000L, 
1100000L, 1400000L, 672000L, 1000000L, 1200000L, 736000L, 1000000L, 
683000L, 812000L, 1300000L, 241000L, 999000L, 953000L, 1900000L, 
1300000L, 100000L, 1500000L, 1300000L, 100000L, 706000L, 1500000L, 
1200000L, 2200000L, 138L, 151L, 3500L, 2700L, 12L, 5500L, 206L, 
1300L, 933L, 4000L, 1500L, 625L, 1700L, 2100L, 130L, 3500L, 1300L, 
1600L, 1750L, 3600L, 168L, 980L, 126L, 147L, 1100L, 1500L, 3500L, 
4300L, 1200L, 3700L, 2600L, 760L, 2700L, 2500L, 156L, 130L, 1700L, 
87L, 975L, 1200L, 2300L, 140L, 2300L, 1800L, 98L, 1900L, 2700L, 
1700L, 150L, 2000L, 1200L, 3700L, 156L, 2400L, 3700L, 155L, 1500L, 
2000L, 778L, 981L, 123L, 3700L, 985L, 2100L, 74L, 93L, 120L, 
660L, 177L, 134L, 169L, 1500L, 1300L, 1100L, 1000000L, 173798L, 
184350L, 349668L, 169722L, 370084L, 41196L, 227641L, 139077L, 
170818L, 195434L, 275576L, 23964L, 215125L, 222401L, 238528L, 
186610L, 242546L, 230264L, 160129L, 155294L, 104889L, 363315L, 
62592L, 258133L, 213028L, 42128L, 268633L, 54758L, 271158L, 340032L, 
636786L, 50978L, 324209L, 458008L, 61564L, 263577L, 260373L, 
255664L, 90504L, 79281L, 86542L, 247029L, 247392L, 273509L, 678358L, 
498855L, 219236L, 440383L, 58323L, 441537L, 222854L, 106647L, 
169164L, 74627L, 243347L, 576549L, 691629L, 564120L, 161433L, 
347161L, 243750L, 239125L, 177537L, 100315L, 449977L, 33364L, 
539864L, 147940L, 63055L, 162502L, 47826L, 455215L, 178912L, 
347571L, 110622L, 60700L, 13000L, 78400L, 15400L, 124000L, 68100L, 
36700L, 61400L, 34800L, 38900L, 86900L, 24200L, 16000L, 53900L, 
51600L, 58300L, 32700L, 40600L, 47600L, 200000L, 29900L, 71300L, 
102000L, 27000L, 26800L, 31800L, 81400L, 15200L, 38200L, 325000L, 
133000L, 121000L, 35300L, 93400L, 46100L, 60000L, 50600L, 34000L, 
94000L, 48000L, 98000L, 206000L, 47000L, 29000L, 18000L, 42000L, 
162000L, 49000L, 51000L, 31000L, 37000L, 161000L, 83000L, 29000L, 
105000L, 48000L, 27000L, 57000L, 48000L, 21000L, 57000L, 86000L, 
112000L, 126000L, 309000L, 65000L, 48000L, 76000L, 22000L, 59000L, 
23000L, 123000L, 55000L, 72000L, 51000L, 202525L, 29241L, 303359L, 
283098L, 395091L, 63690L, 553574L, 103153L, 129810L, 291100L, 
283324L, 75878L, 93428L, 55684L, 86660L, 342016L, 15746L, 199480L, 
11612L, 11336L, 17126L, 99117L, 140578L, 255422L, 8020L, 101428L, 
406858L, 82288L, 87831L, 48572L, 61207L, 446103L, 172178L, 153797L, 
23919L, 603707L, 158060L, 458647L, 405635L, 23537L, 146939L, 
177193L, 190605L, 10845L, 12847L, 303696L, 183960L, 608762L, 
57376L, 621922L, 285299L, 257097L, 114347L, 294125L, 157214L, 
52844L, 130187L, 10213L, 415479L, 126313L, 90319L, 87047L, 78808L, 
348451L, 272894L, 236654L, 325456L, 198106L, 459927L, 164522L, 
279294L, 340502L, 164667L, 125458L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-449L), .Names = c("Player", "Theme", "fb_Likes"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Player, Theme) %>% summarise(Likes = mean(fb_Likes)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% #Change made here
  group_by(Player) %>% #and here
  mutate(ismax = ifelse(Likes == max(Likes), "Max", "NotMax")) %>% #and here
  ggplot(aes(x = Theme, y = Likes), color = "white") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(group = Player, fill = ismax)) + #and here
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#888888', '#333333') ) +
  theme_tufte(base_size = 12, 
              base_family = "sans", 
              ticks = TRUE) + 
  coord_flip() +   
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.background = element_blank()) +
  facet_grid(Player ~., space = "free")
```

[image]

I added a column, `ismax`, to the data to find the `Theme` which was max for each `Player`. Then you do your `fill` aesthetic on that column. It might be possible to do all of this within the call to `ggplot`, but I did it prior to the call.